# How to launch an exe file automatically after download in java

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a requirement like Download an exe file ,once it is downloaded run the same exe file.
Environment is Java web application with tomcat as a server.

I am able to download the file but when I am trying to run the exe file it is running as a background process and hence not able to perform installation.

Need an immediate solution .I got stuck here more than a month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you need graphical interaction after .exe runs?

Comment: You're going to have to narrow it down. It's impossible to come up with a clear answer to this question. I don't know anything about executing binaries on Windows, but this sounds like a client side problem.

Comment: What method are you currently employing? Are you using `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: @Seph, Yes I need installation wizard after .exe runs. But its not showing the wizard. It is running as a backgroud process.

Comment: Your title is misleading, if you download a file from a web server then it is not relevant for its use wherther the server is tomcat or whatsoever and what server it is aa web app or whatsoever. The server just sends the file to the client. Assuming it does it correctly. The file should do what it should. If it is an exe and it has a GUI then it should show it up, assuming the client's OS can run it. Does the program run on the same machine you download it on it word if copied there manually? How does your web app serve the file?

Comment: To check the integrity of the file please process a hash sum `md5` or `sha1` and check the downloaded file whether it has the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

Which code you are using? I think this should work for you:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("YOUR_EXE_FILE_PATH");
```

Comment: This would run the program on the web server where the Java application is running.  I *think* the question is asking how to make a client download and run the file, not how to run it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

A web application can provide an `.exe` file for the user to download, but it can't force the user's browser to run it after it's been downloaded.  Browsers are specifically designed to prevent that, because it could be used to install malware on the user's computer.

You'll need to provide instructions telling the user how to run the program after downloading it.